Deploying .NET 4.7.2 version in an ec2 using Windows also github
So, I deployed it. But I'm getting a problem like when I am opening with publish IP is shown like this
65.0.19.117 - /
 12/5/2024  6:41 AM        <dir> alturasphere
 12/5/2024  8:37 AM          168 web.config

I am trying very hard I am not getting properly, please anyone can help me with this? Thank you.
I am expecting output with help of public IP
